# ggplot2 color gradient in each x values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, 2d

I am trying to create a plot in ggplot2 with a color gradiant inside each x values in order to highlight a third variable in a 2d plot. I tried this but without any success:

```
d = data.frame('y' = sample(0:10, 20, T), 'x' = sample(1:2, 20, T), 'z' = 
sample(0:100, 20) )
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "white"))

d = d[order(d$z),]

d$color = NA
for (i in seq(length(unique(d$x)))) {
d[d$x %in% unique(d$x)[i] ,]$color=colfunc(nrow(d[d$x %in% unique(d$x)[i],]))
}
ggplot2::ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(aes(colour = color))
```

Comment: `?scale_color_identity` will do what you want. But more generally, instead of manually creating your color mapping, use the built in tools.

Comment: E.g. `ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = factor(x)))+geom_point() + scale_color_grey()` will do basically what are you doing automatically.